# javascript function returns -1 always seems unreachable

Tags: javascript

I am working on a patch of code the test always comes out -1 as a return 
does this if statement make the later portion unreachable ? i am thinking no matter what the value of ypos that it will always return -1 ?

```
export function showPreview(content: any , xpos: any, ypos: number, ybot:   any) {
if (!(ypos > 100 || ypos < 100 || ypos === 100)) {
    return -1;
}
hidePreview();
positionPreview(xpos, ypos, ybot);
return 1;
```

Comment: please add what you like to test and when to return with `-1`.

Comment: How can you get `-1` as in your deceleration you have `ypos:number` ? are you passing proper input ?

Comment: Is this Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you hand over `NaN` or `undefined` or just `'100'`.

```js
var ypos = '100';

if (!(ypos > 100 || ypos < 100 || ypos === 100)) {
    console.log(-1);
}
```

Comment: Also if `ypos` is `'100'` (> and < coerce it into a number (being false) and === will fail)

Comment: `ypos: number` ... Typescript will exclude `undefined` and `'100'`, only `NaN` is a possible value. (or the code shown isn't TS)

Comment: @JonasWilms, i have no idea of typescript, but thank you for clarification.

Comment: @JonasWilms but it is possible to get `undefined` (or even string) at run time? Depending upon how OP is calling it.

Comment: @adiga, yes, but in that case the OP has to do a very unsafe typecast, e.g. `"3" as number` and then that is the actual problem

Comment: @JonasWilms If OP gets `ypos` like this: `let ypos = [1,2].find(n => n > 3)`, typescript won't throw any error. It's also possible `ypos` value comes from the server and wrong type is mentioned in the `interface` or if  `any` is used where `showPreview` is called